# Why does mergeMap flatten if the identity is passed?

Tags: rxjs

I am trying to understand why Rxjs' `mergeMap` flattens when the identity function is passed in

```
of(['click', 'tap'])
  .pipe(
      mergeMap(_ => _),
      tap(console.log) // Gets called twice, first with 'click' then with 'tap'
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Whereas in this case it is not:

```
of(['click', 'tap'])
  .pipe(
      mergeMap(_ => Promise.resolve(_)),
      tap(console.log) // Gets called once with ['click', 'tap']
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: All the higher order mapping operators, internally use `from` on the received value. When the value is an observable, the behavior is to emit emissions from that observable. When the received value is an array, the behavior is to emit each array element individually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `mergeMap` operator, like the `concatMap` and `switchMap` operators, takes a function of type `(value: T, index: number) => O` as a parameter, where `O extends ObservableInput<any>`.
This is different from a simpler operator, such as `map`, which takes a function of type `(value: T, index: number) => R`, where `R` is the type of the value returned by the function itself.

This implies that everything you return in the `mergeMap` function must extend from `ObservableInput`, which is simply:

```
 type ObservableInput<T> = Observable<T> | InteropObservable<T> | AsyncIterable<T> | PromiseLike<T> | ArrayLike<T> | Iterable<T> | ReadableStreamLike<T>;
```

So when you use the identity function to return a `string[]`, `mergeMap` will understand that value as `ArrayLike<string>`. The fact that it is flattening the array is to be expected, as it creates a `Subscription` for each value of the `ArrayLike<string>`.

In the case of `Promise.resolve(_)`, it interprets it as a `PromiseLike`, that is, it creates a promise with the emitted value, which happens to be an array. It turns the `Promise<string[]>` into an `Observable<string[]>` internally. The result would be the same if you run the code below:

```
   of(['click', 'tap'])
     .pipe(
       mergeMap((x) => of(x)),
       tap(console.log)
     )
     .subscribe();
```

Hope I helped you! See https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap for more information.